# JavaScript Doesn't do anythign when I click button

Tags: javascript

```
        var timeout = false;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       timeout = true; 
    }, 3000);
    $("#waitForClick").on('click',function(){
      if(!timeout)
       alert("Please comment this website in comments of games."); 
      else
        window.location = "step3.php";
    });
```

What it should do is wait 3 seconds and alert them a message before redirecting to the next page.

Comment: the $ shouldnt be there on line 5 so i removed that but still don't work...

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you are clicking on an element with `waitForClick` ID? (The `$` definitely has to be there, if you're using jQuery; if not, then the code should give you an error. Do you?)

Comment: heres what my button looks like i put back the $ and it still don't work and dont work without it either.

Comment: <button id="waitForClick">Next Step</button>

Comment: To repeat my concerns from the previous comment: `$` is jQuery (or a compatible library's main object). Do you load jQuery? Is there an error in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes i have jQuery loaded and eys i believe so the error is: Uncaught TypeError: Wait for click.on is not a function.

Comment: That error message is impossible given the code you have posted. Please copy both the code and the error message exactly. (Also, the code won't wait three seconds after the click, then redirect; when you click, it will either show a message or redirect, depending on whether 3 seconds has elapsed from when the code has run, presumably since page load.)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the setTimeout inside of the on click function... I'm assuming you want to wait three seconds AFTER you click?

Comment: When the user clicks i want them to be redirected after 3 seconds.

Comment: Now its saying $ is not defined.

Comment: Depends on how you put it into the function... but I was thinking of how Dontfeedthecode implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for some reason jsfiddle isn't letting me save anything at the moment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#waitForClick').on('click', function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("Please comment this website in comments of games."); 
            window.location = "step3.php";
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to put your code inside a document.ready... and it's works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var timeout = false;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        timeout = true; 
    }, 3000);

    $("#waitForClick").click(function(){
        if(!timeout){
            alert("Please comment this website in comments of games."); 
        }else{
            window.location = "step3.php";
        }
    });
});
```

Your element was not loaded when you called.
Please do not forget to import jQuery!

(Sorry for my bad english)